# Visual Studio iOS: XAML HOT RELOAD stopped working on iOS

Tags: visual-studio

I am working from mac and three days ago hot reload on iOS stopped working entierly. It works on Android. The console however says that:

```
Target XamlG:
  Skipping target "XamlG" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.01

Generated file successfully.
```

Ofcourse, Hot reload is enabled everywhere.
I stopped working on other solutions as well, so it cant be a nuget package or anything.

I tried different xamarin.forms packages, but none made any difference.

I tried VS 2019 and VS 2022 pre.

VS 2022 states also:

```
[5:07:22 PM]  XAML Hot Reload is using 'full page' mode
[5:07:46 PM]  Xaml Changed for 'Pages/MainMenu/Page_Main_Home.xaml' in 'asd', sending to app...
```

Can anybody help me out here?